# fields in class Meta got invalid

Tags: django, django-forms

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=5,max_digits= 1500)
    summary = models.TextField()
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        # return f'product title:{self.title}-product price:{self.price}'workok
    class Meta:
         ordering = ('-price',)


class Opinion(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
        body = models.TextField()
        opinion_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='opinion_set')

        def __str__(self):
            return f'({self.name}) add opinion about ({self.product})'
```

### forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Product  #space after from keyword

class OpinionModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','email','body','product']



invalid in code line :
 fields = ['name','email','body','product']      #---- NOT WORK !!!
```

, but if i change above code to :

```
fields = "__all__"           # ----it is WORKing ok without any problem !!
```

question : what is the error? I am not need all the fields in the Product model (like active boolean field), I need only 'name','email','body','product' fields .

Comment: Past here full exception message. It should say what field is invalide and also past here the your `Product` model code.

Comment: exception message say that :
    from .forms import (CreateModelForm,OpinionModelForm)
  File "C:\Users\mayal\Desktop\all_my_try\my_Django_try\product_opinion\src\proj_product\app_product\forms.py", line 12, in <module>
    class OpinionModelForm(ModelForm):
  File "C:\Users\mayal\Desktop\all_my_try\my_Django_try\product_opinion\src\vir_product\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 267, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (email, body, name, product) specified for Product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error and the code you provided the main problem is that you made a mistake in chosing model in serializer:

```
class OpinionModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name','email','body','product']
```

Serializer name is `OpinionModelForm` and listed fields belong to `Opinion` so I guess you actually wanted to serialize `Opinion` and no `Product` as you defined at this line:

```
model = Product
```

Simply change it to:

```
model = Opinion
```